# Manipulating data before drawing columns with DataTables jQuery Library

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I currently have a table that loads data from a REST API endpoint via AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#pendingTable').DataTable({
        ajax: {
            type: "GET",
            url: url + '/rest/endpoint,
            dataSrc: "_deployments"
        },

    columns: [
        { data: "service_name" },
        { data: "git_organization" },
        { data: "id" },
        { data: "timestamp" },
        { data: "username" },
        { data: "environment" },
        { data: "site" },
        { data: "status" }
    ],
    fnCreatedRow: function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex ) {
        $(nRow).attr('onclick', "openModal(" + aData["id"] + ")");
    },
    order: [
        [2, 'sc']
    ]
});
$('.table-responsive').css('opacity', '0').fadeTo(500, 1, 'swing');
$('#pendingTable_filter input').attr("placeholder", "by User, Org & More");
});
```

I have been exploring the DataTables.net docs, but am having issues determining the best course of action for manipulating the "timestamp" data (i.e., format it into a proper date), prior to the table being drawn.

The API offers the ability to modify individual cells which I may be able to iterate through, columns, or both.  How would I go about formatting this time-stamp? (the value is just a string representing milliseconds). Would I need to have some form of a callback, or should I manipulate the data after the table has already been drawn?

Any examples would be greatly appreciated. Apologies that I do not have any examples to offer of what I've tried, a majority of it has been pseudo-code that isn't doing what I thought it would.

Comment: can use columnDefs render https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I've done it using [render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render), which allows you to manipulate the data before it's displayed.

```
{ data: "id" },
{ 
    'render': function (data, type, full, meta) {
        var date = new Date(parseInt(data.substr(6), 0));
        return ISODateString(date);
    }
},
{ data: "username" },
```

I created a function called `ISODateString` that returns the date, month and year parts of the timestamp (obviously you can also return the time parts if necessary).

```
function ISODateString(d) {
    function pad(n) { return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n }
    return pad(d.getDate()) + '/' + pad(d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getFullYear();
}
```